# Django model a pair

Tags: django, model, relation

i am currently playing with django and i want to model a simple relation: two members of a dance-club should be paired as a dancing couple in order to participate in a dancing-tournament. I already have a simple model for the members:

```
class Member(models.Model):
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  lastname  = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  member_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

I also have a tournament Model:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

Since a participant in a tournament is a couple i need to define a couple-relation (at least that would be my guess). But i really don't get how i'd do that.

tia for any help and tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could maybe try defining a model called something like Couple, and two foreign key relationships to the the Member table, with a relationship to the Tournament they are in:

```
class Couple(models.Model):
    partner_a = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    partner_b = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
```

I'm not sure of your requirements, but the way I presented allows members to be part of multiple couples, and a couple is unique to a tournament. Depending on how you want do it, you may want to have couples to be fixed (i.e Stacey and Bob always dance together).  In that case you would probably want to have a many-to-many relationship from Tournament to couple:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    couples = models.manyToManyField(Couple)
```

So a couple can be in many tournaments, and a tournament can have many couples.

Comment: Thanks. You're proposed code didn't work for me at first (you have to set the related_name attribute) but it fits best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OneToOneField relation to map members to other members.

```
class Member(models.Model):
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  lastname  = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  member_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
  partner = models.OneToOneField('Member', unique=True) #This should suffice.
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that a registered member can potentially take part in more than one tournaments, and pair up with different people down the road.

But within a tournament, each member can only be part of one pair.

If the above holds, I would do,

```
class TournamentRegistration(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey("Tournament")
    dancer_1 = models.ForeignKey("Member")
    dancer_2 = models.ForeignKey("Member")
    # ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to give each member a partner:

```
partner = models.OneToOneField('self')
```

But you might want to have the coupling only done per tournament, so the Member class might not be the best place. You could create a Couple class per tournament:

```
class Couple(models.Model):
  tournament = models.ForeignKey('Tournament')
  member1 = models.ForeignKey('Member')
  member2 = models.ForeignKey('Member')
```